# Javascript Tabs - For loop explanation

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, tabs

I have searched everywhere for a "monkey-level" explanation for this and couldn't find anywhere. I am studying JS and I was trying to create tabs inside a page, everything is fine except I can't understand a piece of code in the W3SCHOOLS example.

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Question:

What is the purpose of the for loop there? Why is there an "i" variable? Why tabcontent/links.length is used in the condition?

I would greatly appreciate any help from you. Thank you!

Comment: [MDN: `for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement)

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I studied them on SoloLearn and on W3schools. I just don't know when exactly apply loops and why the i = 0 variable.

Comment: I understand everything else quite well, except this part with the `(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)`

Comment: just for another source to read, have you looked at [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops) explanation of the *initialization, condition* and *afterthought* parts of a for-loop?

Comment: Are you confused by the for-loop itself or that the `getElementsByClassName` is returning all divs, span, etc that have the class name of "tablinks" in the form of a NodeList (or think of it as an array) and they iterate over each one in the for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use loops when you need to repeat a set of actions a number of times.

In this example you are getting al the elements with the class "tablinks" and saving them in a variable named tablinks. Imagine this variable like a box.

```
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
```

Now you are going to execute an action to each of the elements (tablinks) in the box.

You first declare a dummy variable "i", this variable lives and dies in the loop, you initialize the variable with the value zero (0), this should be the part "i=0", you use this variable to iterate over the elements in the box.

There are N elements in the box. To know how much elements are there you use tablikns.length, the attribute length tells you the amount of tablinks in the variable tablink.

Now you started a variable i= 0 and you need to repeat the instructions "tablink.length" times, so you need to increment the counter "i" each time you run an iteration, this is done using the "i++" part.

When the counter reach the value tablinks.length you stop iterating and continue with the rest of the code. This is the part: " i < tablinks.length"

Finally all that is written like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
   tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
```

If there are 3 elements in the box and you start the variable i with value 0, the condition "i < tablinks.length" is true for the values i = 0,1 and 2. When i=3 the condition is false and you exit the loop, so you did 3 iterations.

Hope i got it clear to you.

Regards.

Comment: Ah that explains it! I was convinced the .lenght calculated the amount of characters in each tablinks class which confused me and made me wonder what's the purpose of it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, the first for loop used to go through each and every element that has class name "tabcontent", and the second every element with the class name "tablinks".

The variable "i" in a loop stands for index, it's just convention to use the letter i.

The function getElementsByClassName("tabcontent") will return a collection of all elements with the class name "tabcontent". It's the same for "tablinks".

tabcontent.length will return 3, since there are 3 elements that have class name "tabcontent", and we want to go through all of them in our loop.

tabcontent[i] will access that element, so in the first step of our loop, when i = 0, tabcontent[0] will give us the first element since arrays always start at 0.

So, in this example, the loop will go 0, 1, 2 and then terminate, since the condition i < tabscontent.length is not met when i = 3.

Try reading more about For Loops:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

and Arrays:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp